# Different jumps between tap and held down (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Im making a 2D game for a mobile phone
I need to have a small and large jump for the character
I've had a lot of trouble getting unity to tell the difference between a tap (for a small jump) and holding down (for a large jump).

Comment: just calculate the input time that passes over the tap itself.

Comment: I try this, using a countDown timer but it frequently ends up applying both cases

Comment: could you add the piece of code to the post, so the community could help you out better? Else we won't know what you tried / are trying

Comment: Are you using physics or translation for jumping?

Comment: At the moment I am using addforce with impulse to apply the different jumps

Comment: @KingReload
at the moment I don't really have any code, everything I've tried just reads the input as both held down and single press

Comment: Maybe a screenshot for a better overview?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the character is airborne and that the velocity is not 0 and in an upwards direction. If this is the case, it means the character has (most likely) jumped. Then, if this is true, after a short time (use a timer here), we also check if the player is still pressing the screen or not. If they are still pressing the screen, add more force to the character until the height of the larger jump is reached.

Pseudocode:

```
if (player presses screen) 
{
    // Add small impulse to make the character jump to the "minimum jump height"

    // Start timer    

    if (character's velocity is upwards and they are not grounded)
    {
        if (timer is greater than your chosen time)
        {
            // Add another impulse so character jumps to the "maximum jump height"
            // Stop and reset timer
        }
    }
}
```

This is a basic plan, it's not perfect but it should get you started; there are many ways to do this - you may want to consider using `Force` rather than `Impulse` if you want a truly variable jump height. See the Unity docs for [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html).

**Note:** It is better practice to apply physics based actions inside `FixedUpdate()` rather than in `Update()`. This makes it more complicated as you would usually want to check for player input in `Update()` but is a necessary step to avoid problems with physics based actions.